# what is the relationship between epsilon and sensitivity in the Differential-Privacy?

Tags: differential-privacy

In some Differential-Privacy(DP) papers, they use epsilon as the x-axis in the figures of the experiments' result while other papers use the sensitivity.

1. What is the relationship between epsilon and sensitivity in the DP?
2. How can I compare the results of different papers?

Answer (score 3):

I'll answer the second question first. The two are distinct concepts — there's no way directly compare graphs or results without more info or context.

Differential privacy is usually obtained by 1. computing a function $F$ of the data and 2. adding some *noise* to the result. The noise must be large enough to hide an individual contribution, and "how well an individual contribution is hidden" is captured by the parameter $\varepsilon$.

But for some functions $F$, an individual contribution can change the true result more than for others functions. For example:

- The answer to "how many employees of this company have blue eyes?" can only change by one if you add or remove an employee.
- The answer to "what's the average salary of people in this company?" can change by *a lot* if you remove the CEO's salary.

That concept is captured by sensitivity: the higher the possible change, the higher the sensitivity. And typically, to get $\varepsilon$-differential privacy with a fixed $\varepsilon$, you have to add more noise when the sensitivity is larger (to compensate). That's the typical relationship between the two concepts.

Comment: There is an interesting paper discussing what are good values for ε for various usage scenarios:
J. Lee, C. Clifton, “How much is enough? Choosing ε for differential privacy,” Proceedings of the International Conference on Information Security, Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg, 2011